# Tokeninput - how to get results onReady

Tags: jquery-tokeninput

I'm using tokeninput. While getting the results onAdd and onDelete works great, the onReady doesn't. Chrome console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTokens' of undefined.". I need to save not only inserted tokens but also those from PrePopulation and I guess that's what the script cannot handle. Or I'm doing something wrong.

```
    onAdd: function (item) {
projectresults=$("#inputproject").tokenInput("get");
console.log($(projectresults).serializeArray()); },

    onReady: function (item) {
projectresults=$("#inputproject").tokenInput("get");
console.log($(projectresults).serializeArray()); },

    onDelete: function (item) {
projectresults=$("#inputproject").tokenInput("get");
console.log($(projectresults).serializeArray());
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should work how it is, is your prepopulate working correctly? Can you provide all your code for the tokenInput? Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps have a look at this? https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/246